# Does /invalidate work for no-expiry tokens?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It seems that tokens created with `no_expiry` scope are immune to requests to invalidate them with `/access-tokens/.../invalidate`. Is this by design or by bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

Invalidation should be possible for any access token, regardless of its properties.